# Flask socketio server + React socket.io-client connection refused

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, socket.io

I'm not able to connect from React frontend to python backend.

This is the error

```
polling-xhr.js:268 GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NEzs39W net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

frontend side code ( listening on http://localhost:3000 ):

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import io from "socket.io-client";

class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

       socket.on('connect', (error) => {
           console.log(error);
       });
   }

   render() {
       return <h1>Hi!</h1>
   }
};

render(
   <App />,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

backend side code:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*":{"origins":"*"}})
socket = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

What's wrong with my code?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here you shouldn't assign any variable to `CORS`:

```
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*":{"origins":"*"}})
```

instead try using:

```
 CORS(app, resources={r"/*":{"origins":"*"}})
```

Comment: Still not connecting after the change you suggest

Comment: No Errors. Only the same message of connection refused on the browser